# how to figure out which type is passed to a template-defined function?

Tags: c++, templates, structure

I have a problem doing my homework. the problem I faced is this:
the question is this:
((write a program that prints the name of the human/employee with maximum sort_param.use template programming.))
human and employee are defined like this:

```
struct human
{
char name[30];
char * family;
int id;
int sort_param;
};

struct employee
{
human h;
char post[50];
int sort_param;
};
```

as you see, printing the name of the employee/human depends on the type that is passed to the function.
my question is:
how can I tell the computer to act depend on the data type. I mean if the type is employee  then:

```
cout << employee.h.name << endl;
```

if the type is human then:

```
cout << human.name << endl;
```

Comment: Have the name printed from a function overloaded on `employee` and `human` (well, `const` references thereof) instead of printing it directly. The usual rule applies: an extra level of indirection solves the problem. With C++17 you could use `if constexpr` but that isn't really available, yet.

Comment: *write a program that prints the name of the human/employee with maximum sort_param.use template programming.* What's the input to the function/program?

Comment: If you need to know the type, a template is the wrong approach. You should overload the function instead. Even on a smaller scale, like Dietmar Kühl suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an overloaded function, just call your function with one of arguments those type can be *human* or *employee*.

```
void print_name(const employee& emp)
{
     cout << emp.h.name << endl;
}
void print_name(const human& hum)
{
     cout << hum.name << endl;
}
```

*The argument are edited.*

Comment: Surely, that should be `void print_name(const employee& emp) { ... }`, etc. The question is tagged [tag:c++] for a reason, no?

Comment: i did'nt want to use function overloading. but i think this is the most efficient and usefull one. anyway, thank you!